# React-Bootstrap overwriting styles issue

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, react-bootstrap

I decided to use react-bootstrap at one single route among others. I imported bootstrap CSS ONLY to my component and it looks good. But when I go to other routes, bootstrap overrides styles there, too (it affects everything: paragraphs, titles, etc). If I update the page at another route - styles become good, according to my custom sass styles. Is it possible to make Bootstrap styles work ONLY on one route and don't affect other routes?

```
App.js
---
import { MyComponent } from './components/MyComponent/MyComponent';
...
<Route path="/mycomponent" render={
  () =>
  <MyComponent
     ...props
  />
} />
```

```
MyComponent.jsx
---
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './css/MyComponent.css';
```

I didn't import Bootstrap CSS styles to other components

Comment: when  you import css file to react components, that css affected to all of your components. you must change the other css classes

Comment: @Shahbaz there's no other solution?

Comment: Why are they overriding the styles in your other component ? Have you used the bootstrap class names like row, col, etc. According to my understanding the only way they will override your styles is if you have the same names. That being said, you can also override bootstrap classes by writing your own css and importing it after bootstrap css.

Comment: @HarshaLimaye where can I check all bootstrap classes?

Comment: are you able to share the component where you don't want bootstrap to override the styles ?